# Porting to newer OpenCV 'C' interface; cv.h file not found

Tags: c, opencv, gcc, compiler-errors

I have a file, included below, that when I compile, I get the error that `cv.h file not found`. This, I believe, is because I use opencv4 which doesn't support `cv.h`. I've seen similar posts recommending one to simply downgrade opencv versions, but I don't want to do that.

My question is this:

How do I find what part of the code is dependent on `cv.h`, so that. I can simply try to update it for opencv4 compatibility?

file:

```
#ifndef _GUARD_cvl1qc_h_
#define _GUARD_cvl1qc_h_

#include <cv.h>
#include "cvcgsolve.h"

/* taken A, B, X, minimize ||X||_{L1} with constraint: ||AX - B|| < \epsilon */
int cvL1QCSolve( CvMat* A, CvMat* B, CvMat* X, double epsilon, double mu = 10., CvTermCriteria lb_term_crit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 0, 1e-3 ), CvTermCriteria cg_term_crit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 200, 1e-16 ) );

/* taken AOps, AtOps, it specially designed for large scale, AOps is for AX, AtOps is for A'X */
int cvL1QCSolve( CvMatOps AOps, CvMatOps AtOps, void* userdata, CvMat* B, CvMat* X, double epsilon, double mu = 10., CvTermCriteria lb_term_crit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 0, 1e-3 ), CvTermCriteria cg_term_crit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER + CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 200, 1e-16 ) );



static int icvL1QCNewton( CvMat* A, CvMat* B, CvMat* X, CvMat* U, double epsilon, double tau, CvTermCriteria nt_term_crit, CvTermCriteria cg_term_crit )
{
    const double alpha = .01;
    const double beta = .5;
    
    CvMat* R = cvCreateMat( B->rows, B->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(B->type) );
    cvGEMM( A, X, 1, B, -1, R );
    CvMat* fu1 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* fu2 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* lfu1 = cvCreateMat( fu1->rows, fu1->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu1->type) );
    CvMat* lfu2 = cvCreateMat( fu2->rows, fu2->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu2->type) );
    cvSub( U, X, lfu1 );
    cvAdd( X, U, lfu2 );
    cvSubRS( lfu1, cvScalar(0), fu1 );
    cvSubRS( lfu2, cvScalar(0), fu2 );
    double epsilon2 = epsilon * epsilon;
    double tau_inv = 1. / tau;
    double fe = .5 * (cvDotProduct( R, R ) - epsilon2);
    double fe_inv = 1. / fe;
    cvLog( lfu1, lfu1 );
    cvLog( lfu2, lfu2 );
    CvScalar sumU = cvSum( U );
    CvScalar sumfu1 = cvSum( lfu1 );
    CvScalar sumfu2 = cvSum( lfu2 );
    double f = sumU.val[0] - tau_inv * (sumfu1.val[0] + sumfu2.val[0] + log(-fe));

    CvMat* atr = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* ntgx = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* ntgu = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* sig1211 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* sigx = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* w1 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* AtA = cvCreateMat( A->cols, A->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(A->type) );
    CvMat* H11 = cvCreateMat( A->cols, A->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(A->type) );
    CvMat* du = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* pX = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* pU = cvCreateMat( U->rows, U->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(U->type) );
    CvMat* pR = cvCreateMat( R->rows, R->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(R->type) );
    CvMat* pfu1 = cvCreateMat( fu1->rows, fu1->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu1->type) );
    CvMat* pfu2 = cvCreateMat( fu2->rows, fu2->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu2->type) );
    CvMat* Adx = cvCreateMat( B->rows, B->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(B->type) );
    CvMat* dx = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );

    int result = nt_term_crit.max_iter;

    int t, i;

    for ( t = 0; t < nt_term_crit.max_iter; ++t )
    {
        cvGEMM( A, R, 1, NULL, 0, atr, CV_GEMM_A_T );
        cvGEMM( A, A, 1, NULL, 0, AtA, CV_GEMM_A_T );
        cvGEMM( atr, atr, 1, NULL, 0, H11, CV_GEMM_B_T );
        double* atrp = atr->data.db;
        double* fu1p = fu1->data.db;
        double* fu2p = fu2->data.db;
        double* ntgxp = ntgx->data.db;
        double* ntgup = ntgu->data.db;
        double* sig1211p = sig1211->data.db;
        double* sigxp = sigx->data.db;
        double* w1p = w1->data.db;
        double* dup = du->data.db;
        for ( i = 0; i < X->rows; ++i, ++atrp, ++fu1p, ++fu2p, ++ntgxp, ++ntgup, ++sig1211p, ++sigxp, ++w1p, ++dup )
        {
            double fu1_inv = 1. / (*fu1p);
            double fu2_inv = 1. / (*fu2p);
            double ntgxv = fu1_inv - fu2_inv + fe_inv * (*atrp);
            double ntguv = -tau - fu1_inv - fu2_inv;
            double sig11 = fu1_inv * fu1_inv + fu2_inv * fu2_inv;
            double sig12 = -fu1_inv * fu1_inv + fu2_inv * fu2_inv;
            *sig1211p = sig12 / sig11;
            *sigxp = sig11 - sig12 * (*sig1211p);
            *w1p = ntgxv - (*sig1211p) * ntguv;
            *ntgxp = -tau_inv * ntgxv;
            *ntgup = -tau_inv * ntguv;
            *dup = ntguv / sig11;
        }
        cvAddWeighted( AtA, -fe_inv, H11, -fe_inv * fe_inv, 0, H11 );
        sigxp = sigx->data.db;
        double* H11p = H11->data.db;
        for ( i = 0; i < A->cols; ++i, ++sigxp, H11p += A->cols + 1 )
            *H11p += *sigxp;
        if ( cvCGSolve( H11, w1, dx, cg_term_crit ) > .5 )
        {
            result = t;
            goto __clean_up__;
        }
        cvMatMul( A, dx, Adx );
        dup = du->data.db;
        sig1211p = sig1211->data.db;
        double* dxp = dx->data.db;
        for ( i = 0; i < X->rows; ++i, ++dup, ++sig1211p, ++dxp )
            *dup -= (*sig1211p) * (*dxp);

        /* minimum step size that stays in the interior */
        double aqe = cvDotProduct( Adx, Adx );
        double bqe = 2. * cvDotProduct( R, Adx );
        double cqe = cvDotProduct( R, R ) - epsilon2;
        double smax = MIN( 1, -bqe + sqrt( bqe * bqe - 4 * aqe * cqe ) / (2 * aqe) );
        dup = du->data.db;
        dxp = dx->data.db;
        fu1p = fu1->data.db;
        fu2p = fu2->data.db;
        for ( i = 0; i < X->rows; ++i, ++dup, ++dxp, ++fu1p, ++fu2p )
        {
            if ( (*dxp) - (*dup) > 0 )
                smax = MIN( smax, -(*fu1p) / ((*dxp) - (*dup)) );
            if ( (*dxp) + (*dup) < 0 )
                smax = MIN( smax, (*fu2p) / ((*dxp) + (*dup)) );
        }
        smax *= .99;

        /* backtracking line search */
        bool suffdec = 0;
        int backiter = 0;
        double fep = fe;
        double fp = f;
        double lambda2;
        while (!suffdec)
        {
            cvAddWeighted( X, 1, dx, smax, 0, pX );
            cvAddWeighted( U, 1, du, smax, 0, pU );
            cvAddWeighted( R, 1, Adx, smax, 0, pR );
            cvSub( pU, pX, lfu1 );
            cvAdd( pX, pU, lfu2 );
            cvSubRS( lfu1, cvScalar(0), pfu1 );
            cvSubRS( lfu2, cvScalar(0), pfu2 );
            fep = .5 * (cvDotProduct( pR, pR ) - epsilon2);
            cvLog( lfu1, lfu1 );
            cvLog( lfu2, lfu2 );
            CvScalar sumpU = cvSum( pU );
            CvScalar sumpfu1 = cvSum( pfu1 );
            CvScalar sumpfu2 = cvSum( pfu2 );
            fp = sumpU.val[0] - tau_inv * (sumpfu1.val[0] + sumpfu2.val[0] + log(-fep));
            lambda2 = cvDotProduct( ntgx, dx ) + cvDotProduct( ntgu, du );
            double flin = f + alpha * smax * lambda2;
            suffdec = (fp <= flin);
            smax = beta * smax;
            ++backiter;
            if ( backiter > 32 )
            {
                result = t;
                goto __clean_up__;
            }
        }

        /* set up for next iteration */
        cvCopy( pX, X );
        cvCopy( pU, U );
        cvCopy( pR, R );
        cvCopy( pfu1, fu1 );
        cvCopy( pfu2, fu2 );
        fe = fep;
        fe_inv = 1. / fe;
        f = fp;
        lambda2 = -lambda2 * .5;
        if ( lambda2 < nt_term_crit.epsilon )
        {
            result = t + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

__clean_up__:

    cvReleaseMat( &pfu2 );
    cvReleaseMat( &pfu1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &pR );
    cvReleaseMat( &pU );
    cvReleaseMat( &pX );
    cvReleaseMat( &dx );
    cvReleaseMat( &Adx );
    cvReleaseMat( &du );
    cvReleaseMat( &H11 );
    cvReleaseMat( &AtA );
    cvReleaseMat( &w1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &sigx );
    cvReleaseMat( &sig1211 );
    cvReleaseMat( &ntgu );
    cvReleaseMat( &ntgx );
    cvReleaseMat( &lfu2 );
    cvReleaseMat( &lfu1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &fu2 );
    cvReleaseMat( &fu1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &R );
    return result;
}

int cvL1QCSolve( CvMat* A, CvMat* B, CvMat* X, double epsilon, double mu, CvTermCriteria lb_term_crit, CvTermCriteria cg_term_crit )
{
    CvMat* AAt = cvCreateMat( A->rows, A->rows, CV_MAT_TYPE(A->type) );
    cvGEMM( A, A, 1, NULL, 0, AAt, CV_GEMM_B_T );
    CvMat* W = cvCreateMat( A->rows, 1, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    if ( cvCGSolve( AAt, B, W, cg_term_crit ) > .5 )
    {
        cvReleaseMat( &W );
        cvReleaseMat( &AAt );
        return -1;
    }
    cvGEMM( A, W, 1, NULL, 0, X, CV_GEMM_A_T );
    cvReleaseMat( &W );
    cvReleaseMat( &AAt );

    CvMat* U = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    cvAbsDiffS( X, U, cvScalar(0) );
    CvScalar sumAbsX = cvSum( U );
    double minAbsX, maxAbsX;
    cvMinMaxLoc( U, &minAbsX, &maxAbsX );
    cvConvertScale( U, U, .95, maxAbsX * .1 );
    
    double tau = MAX( (2 * X->rows + 1) / sumAbsX.val[0], 1 );

    if ( !(lb_term_crit.type & CV_TERMCRIT_ITER) )
        lb_term_crit.max_iter = ceil( (log(2 * X->rows + 1) - log(lb_term_crit.epsilon) - log(tau)) / log(mu) );

    CvTermCriteria nt_term_crit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 50, lb_term_crit.epsilon );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < lb_term_crit.max_iter; ++i )
    {
        icvL1QCNewton( A, B, X, U, epsilon, tau, nt_term_crit, cg_term_crit );
        tau *= mu;
    }

    cvReleaseMat( &U );

    return 0;
}

typedef struct {
    CvMatOps AOps;
    CvMatOps AtOps;
    CvMat* AR;
    CvMat* AtR;
    void* userdata;
} CvAAtOpsData;

static void icvAAtOps( CvMat* X, CvMat* Y, void* userdata )
{
    CvAAtOpsData* data = (CvAAtOpsData*)userdata;
    data->AtOps( X, data->AtR, data->userdata );
    data->AOps( data->AtR, Y, data->userdata );
}

typedef struct {
    CvMatOps AOps;
    CvMatOps AtOps;
    CvMat* AR;
    CvMat* AtR;
    CvMat* tX;
    CvMat* sigx;
    CvMat* atr;
    double fe_inv;
    double fe_inv_2;
    void* userdata;
} CvH11OpsData;

static void icvH11Ops( CvMat* X, CvMat* Y, void* userdata )
{
    CvH11OpsData* h11 = (CvH11OpsData*)userdata;
    h11->AOps( X, h11->AR, h11->userdata );
    h11->AtOps( h11->AR, h11->AtR, h11->userdata );
    double rc = h11->fe_inv_2 * cvDotProduct( h11->atr, X );
    cvAddWeighted( h11->AtR, -h11->fe_inv, h11->atr, rc, 0, h11->AtR );
    cvMul( h11->sigx, X, h11->tX );
    cvAdd( h11->tX, h11->AtR, Y );
}

static int icvL1QCNewton( CvAAtOpsData& AAtData, CvMat* B, CvMat* X, CvMat* U, double epsilon, double tau, CvTermCriteria nt_term_crit, CvTermCriteria cg_term_crit )
{
    const double alpha = .01;
    const double beta = .5;

    CvMat* R = cvCreateMat( B->rows, B->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(B->type) );
    AAtData.AOps( X, AAtData.AR, AAtData.userdata );
    cvSub( AAtData.AR, B, R );
    CvMat* fu1 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* fu2 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* lfu1 = cvCreateMat( fu1->rows, fu1->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu1->type) );
    CvMat* lfu2 = cvCreateMat( fu2->rows, fu2->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu2->type) );
    cvSub( U, X, lfu1 );
    cvAdd( X, U, lfu2 );
    cvSubRS( lfu1, cvScalar(0), fu1 );
    cvSubRS( lfu2, cvScalar(0), fu2 );
    double epsilon2 = epsilon * epsilon;
    double tau_inv = 1. / tau;
    double fe = .5 * (cvDotProduct( R, R ) - epsilon2);
    double fe_inv = 1. / fe;
    cvLog( lfu1, lfu1 );
    cvLog( lfu2, lfu2 );
    CvScalar sumU = cvSum( U );
    CvScalar sumfu1 = cvSum( lfu1 );
    CvScalar sumfu2 = cvSum( lfu2 );
    double f = sumU.val[0] - tau_inv * (sumfu1.val[0] + sumfu2.val[0] + log(-fe));

    CvMat* atr = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* ntgx = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* ntgu = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* sig1211 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* sigx = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* w1 = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* du = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* pX = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* pU = cvCreateMat( U->rows, U->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(U->type) );
    CvMat* pR = cvCreateMat( R->rows, R->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(R->type) );
    CvMat* pfu1 = cvCreateMat( fu1->rows, fu1->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu1->type) );
    CvMat* pfu2 = cvCreateMat( fu2->rows, fu2->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(fu2->type) );
    CvMat* Adx = cvCreateMat( B->rows, B->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(B->type) );
    CvMat* dx = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* tX = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );

    int result = nt_term_crit.max_iter;

    CvH11OpsData H11OpsData;
    H11OpsData.AOps = AAtData.AOps;
    H11OpsData.AtOps = AAtData.AtOps;
    H11OpsData.AR = AAtData.AR;
    H11OpsData.AtR = AAtData.AtR;
    H11OpsData.userdata = AAtData.userdata;
    H11OpsData.tX = tX;
    H11OpsData.atr = atr;
    H11OpsData.sigx = sigx;

    int t, i;

    for ( t = 0; t < nt_term_crit.max_iter; ++t )
    {
        AAtData.AtOps( R, atr, AAtData.userdata );
        double* atrp = atr->data.db;
        double* fu1p = fu1->data.db;
        double* fu2p = fu2->data.db;
        double* ntgxp = ntgx->data.db;
        double* ntgup = ntgu->data.db;
        double* sig1211p = sig1211->data.db;
        double* sigxp = sigx->data.db;
        double* w1p = w1->data.db;
        double* dup = du->data.db;
        for ( i = 0; i < X->rows; ++i, ++atrp, ++fu1p, ++fu2p, ++ntgxp, ++ntgup, ++sig1211p, ++sigxp, ++w1p, ++dup )
        {
            double fu1_inv = 1. / (*fu1p);
            double fu2_inv = 1. / (*fu2p);
            double ntgxv = fu1_inv - fu2_inv + fe_inv * (*atrp);
            double ntguv = -tau - fu1_inv - fu2_inv;
            double sig11 = fu1_inv * fu1_inv + fu2_inv * fu2_inv;
            double sig12 = -fu1_inv * fu1_inv + fu2_inv * fu2_inv;
            *sig1211p = sig12 / sig11;
            *sigxp = sig11 - sig12 * (*sig1211p);
            *w1p = ntgxv - (*sig1211p) * ntguv;
            *ntgxp = -tau_inv * ntgxv;
            *ntgup = -tau_inv * ntguv;
            *dup = ntguv / sig11;
        }
        H11OpsData.fe_inv = fe_inv;
        H11OpsData.fe_inv_2 = fe_inv * fe_inv;
        if ( cvCGSolve( icvH11Ops, &H11OpsData, w1, dx, cg_term_crit ) > .5 )
        {
            result = t;
            goto __clean_up__;
        }
        AAtData.AOps( dx, Adx, AAtData.userdata );
        dup = du->data.db;
        sig1211p = sig1211->data.db;
        double* dxp = dx->data.db;
        for ( i = 0; i < X->rows; ++i, ++dup, ++sig1211p, ++dxp )
            *dup -= (*sig1211p) * (*dxp);

        /* minimum step size that stays in the interior */
        double aqe = cvDotProduct( Adx, Adx );
        double bqe = 2. * cvDotProduct( R, Adx );
        double cqe = cvDotProduct( R, R ) - epsilon2;
        double smax = MIN( 1, -bqe + sqrt( bqe * bqe - 4 * aqe * cqe ) / (2 * aqe) );
        dup = du->data.db;
        dxp = dx->data.db;
        fu1p = fu1->data.db;
        fu2p = fu2->data.db;
        for ( i = 0; i < X->rows; ++i, ++dup, ++dxp, ++fu1p, ++fu2p )
        {
            if ( (*dxp) - (*dup) > 0 )
                smax = MIN( smax, -(*fu1p) / ((*dxp) - (*dup)) );
            if ( (*dxp) + (*dup) < 0 )
                smax = MIN( smax, (*fu2p) / ((*dxp) + (*dup)) );
        }
        smax *= .99;

        /* backtracking line search */
        bool suffdec = 0;
        int backiter = 0;
        double fep = fe;
        double fp = f;
        double lambda2;
        while (!suffdec)
        {
            cvAddWeighted( X, 1, dx, smax, 0, pX );
            cvAddWeighted( U, 1, du, smax, 0, pU );
            cvAddWeighted( R, 1, Adx, smax, 0, pR );
            cvSub( pU, pX, lfu1 );
            cvAdd( pX, pU, lfu2 );
            cvSubRS( lfu1, cvScalar(0), pfu1 );
            cvSubRS( lfu2, cvScalar(0), pfu2 );
            fep = .5 * (cvDotProduct( pR, pR ) - epsilon2);
            cvLog( lfu1, lfu1 );
            cvLog( lfu2, lfu2 );
            CvScalar sumpU = cvSum( pU );
            CvScalar sumpfu1 = cvSum( pfu1 );
            CvScalar sumpfu2 = cvSum( pfu2 );
            fp = sumpU.val[0] - tau_inv * (sumpfu1.val[0] + sumpfu2.val[0] + log(-fep));
            lambda2 = cvDotProduct( ntgx, dx ) + cvDotProduct( ntgu, du );
            double flin = f + alpha * smax * lambda2;
            suffdec = (fp <= flin);
            smax = beta * smax;
            ++backiter;
            if ( backiter > 32 )
            {
                result = t;
                goto __clean_up__;
            }
        }

        /* set up for next iteration */
        cvCopy( pX, X );
        cvCopy( pU, U );
        cvCopy( pR, R );
        cvCopy( pfu1, fu1 );
        cvCopy( pfu2, fu2 );
        fe = fep;
        fe_inv = 1. / fe;
        f = fp;
        lambda2 = -lambda2 * .5;
        if ( lambda2 < nt_term_crit.epsilon )
        {
            result = t + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

__clean_up__:

    cvReleaseMat( &pfu2 );
    cvReleaseMat( &pfu1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &pR );
    cvReleaseMat( &pU );
    cvReleaseMat( &pX );
    cvReleaseMat( &tX );
    cvReleaseMat( &dx );
    cvReleaseMat( &Adx );
    cvReleaseMat( &du );
    cvReleaseMat( &w1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &sigx );
    cvReleaseMat( &sig1211 );
    cvReleaseMat( &ntgu );
    cvReleaseMat( &ntgx );
    cvReleaseMat( &lfu2 );
    cvReleaseMat( &lfu1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &fu2 );
    cvReleaseMat( &fu1 );
    cvReleaseMat( &R );
    return result;
}

int cvL1QCSolve( CvMatOps AOps, CvMatOps AtOps, void* userdata, CvMat* B, CvMat* X, double epsilon, double mu, CvTermCriteria lb_term_crit, CvTermCriteria cg_term_crit )
{
    CvMat* Z = cvCreateMat( X->rows, 1, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    CvMat* W = cvCreateMat( B->rows, 1, CV_MAT_TYPE(B->type) );
    CvAAtOpsData AAtData;
    AAtData.AOps = AOps;
    AAtData.AtOps = AtOps;
    AAtData.AtR = Z;
    AAtData.userdata = userdata;
    if ( cvCGSolve( icvAAtOps, &AAtData, B, W, cg_term_crit ) > .5 )
    {
        cvReleaseMat( &W );
        cvReleaseMat( &Z );
        return -1;
    }
    AtOps( W, X, userdata );
    AAtData.AR = W;

    CvMat* U = cvCreateMat( X->rows, X->cols, CV_MAT_TYPE(X->type) );
    cvAbsDiffS( X, U, cvScalar(0) );
    CvScalar sumAbsX = cvSum( U );
    double minAbsX, maxAbsX;
    cvMinMaxLoc( U, &minAbsX, &maxAbsX );
    cvConvertScale( U, U, .95, maxAbsX * .1 );
    
    double tau = MAX( (2 * X->rows + 1) / sumAbsX.val[0], 1 );

    if ( !(lb_term_crit.type & CV_TERMCRIT_ITER) )
        lb_term_crit.max_iter = ceil( (log(2 * X->rows + 1) - log(lb_term_crit.epsilon) - log(tau)) / log(mu) );

    CvTermCriteria nt_term_crit = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 50, lb_term_crit.epsilon );
    
    int totaliter = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < lb_term_crit.max_iter; ++i )
    {
        totaliter += icvL1QCNewton( AAtData, B, X, U, epsilon, tau, nt_term_crit, cg_term_crit );
        tau *= mu;
    }

    cvReleaseMat( &U );
    cvReleaseMat( &W );
    cvReleaseMat( &Z );

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Brute force: remove the include, compile and examine the error messages.

Comment: Bizarre side note: `_GUARD_cvl1qc_h_` is [an illegal identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). This rarely ever bites you, but when it does the results can be nigh-inscrutable. So painful that it's best avoided no matter how unlikely it is to actually manifest.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I'm too naive to be properly afraid. I hope whatever you're warning against doesn't happen. I'm trying your suggestion and the error lists stops generating after 20. It looks like the name conventions are off (ex. CvMat is no longer supported and is now Mat). I changed the types to their opencv4 name (ex. CvMat to Mat), but now I get errors like 'unknown type name 'Mat'. Why is this?

Comment: It looks like you need/want to use the C-only interface of OpenCV. However all those: cvMat etc. are probably dependend on that "cv.h", that's the only include file in your code. In C++ #include <opencv2/core.hpp> etc. There are headers with "_c.h": core_c.h , types_c.h, imgproc_c.h in order to use these funcitons cvMat, cvAdd etc. (it's just Mat in C++ etc.)

Comment: You have to change the includes then, some sample includes:

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp> 

(#include <opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h> etc. if you want some C types)
etc.

One good source: http://learnopencv.com

Comment: Like I said, it rarely bites. Just be careful how and where you use underscores. Side note: When you have something like `goto __clean_up__;`, consider migrating the involved code to another function and rather than using `goto` return from that function. In this case, the entire `for ( t = 0; t < nt_term_crit.max_iter; ++t )` goes into a function. Replace the `goto`s with `return`. Call the function where the `for` loop was. Immediately after the function call is the clean-up code.

Comment: This isn't a particularly bad `goto`, but it's easy to replace. I find you spend more time defending all but the best use of `goto` in code reviews than you save using the `goto`. Plus the co-op maintaining your code a few years down the road will probably <expletive deleted> it up.

Comment: Why not use the C++ interface and make a function `extern "C"` so you can call from 'C'.  The C++ interface is much more usable/readable for code like this as `cv::Mat` is a high quality class. Btw, I am **NOT** a C++ zealot.  In this case, the argument for C++ is quite extreme.  You are really better off to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the C-interface to OpenCV, not C++. Some of the types seem to be still available, though, with `"_c.h"` header files, if you still want to use the C code and don't want to convert it to the C++ types and interface.

I managed to get most of your code parsed with OpenCV 4.2 and:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core_c.h>
```

However except:

```
CvMatOps, cvCGSolve
```

( I didn't find them in the source either, I just searched the OpenCV include directories for these strings, the latter seems to be in that file cvcgsolve.h which is something specific, it's found here: https://github.com/liuliu/l1cs/blob/master/src/cvcgsolve.cpp )

Illustrations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP has cvcgsolve as an include.  So I think this function is other unposted code where they implement the function using OpenCV.  So I think the **'cv'** is not to denote part of the OpenCV api, but **using** the OpenCV api. [R Conjugate Gradient method](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lfe/versions/2.8-5.1/topics/cgsolve)